# KEY cannot be null - VB.net error

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need your help, guys. I'm having an error. Please see my code below:

```
      Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class frmlogin
Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
Dim serverstring As String = "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=root;Database=dasystem"
Dim login As Boolean
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim cusds As DataSet
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim ctrshowlogin, ctrshowsearch As Integer


Private Sub btnlogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    Dim rowctr As Integer
    Dim password As String
    ctrshowlogin = 0
    ds = New DataSet
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from password", conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "pword")

    If cmbuser.SelectedItem = "Administrator" Then
        For rowctr = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            password = ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowctr).Item(0).ToString
            If password = txtpass.Text Then
                login = True
            End If
        Next (rowctr)
        If login = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!")
            frmcomodities.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            cmbuser.Text = ""
        ElseIf login = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password, Please try again.")
            txtpass.Focus()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Cancel.Click
    Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Any ideas? I'm stuck with this problem. If you could help, I'd gladly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: in this line: da.Fill(ds, "pword")

Comment: Do you have really a table named 'Password'? What is its schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either change the name of the table in the `da.Fill(ds, "pword")` line to match the database table name (password):

```
da.Fill(ds, "password")
```

or just remove that parameter altogether

```
da.Fill(ds)
```